# Volatile Singleton member?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, singleton, volatile

I have a state engine that uses a Singleton software design pattern. The state engine can be accessed by multiple threads. The object is initialized from the main thread at program start up and is not designed for Lazy initialization.

My question is, should I make the public static members volatile like this:

```
class CStateEngine final
{
    private:
        /* Contains the Singleton object */
        static CStateEngine* instance;
    protected:
        CStateEngine();
    public:
        static CStateEngine* Instance() volatile;   // Returns the Singleton instance
        static void DeleteInstance() volatile;  // Deletes the Singleton instance
}
```

Comment: `volatile` is not meant for multithreading. What do you think marking the members as `volatile` would give you?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Fencing? I have implemented locking elsewhere inside the class members though. See [link](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766)

Comment: Singletons aren't meant to be used in multithreaded environment. Adding a keyword doesn't really help here. You would need something like `std::atomic`; `volatile` does something totally different

Comment: Singletons are bad and you are bad for contemplating their use in a multithreaded environment. Go learn proper programming.

Comment: @TonyTheLion As I understand, there is no problem using Singletons in multithreaded environments, but you need to be careful.

Comment: @Inge Sure, where "careful" = "doing the opposite of this"

Comment: @IngeHenriksen That statement is rather in contrary to popular belief, you know?

Comment: @Inge Have you even read the article you linked to? It says nowhere that `volatile` provides fences. It presents an abuse of `volatile` *as nothing but a tag*. The LockingPtr trick actually makes *no use of the `volatile` semantics*, it only uses its tagging properties to mark two distinct contexts (and relies on undefined behaviour to switch between them)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit & TonyTheLion What other design pattern should I use when I have a state engine that is supposed to be shared between multiple threads withing a single process?

Comment: Just pass your object around, and use proper locking for it's shared state, if there is any.

Comment: @Inge If you're looking for a design pattern to use, you are programming _backwards_. Write your code, then find out what pattern you accidentally used _if_ you need to describe it to somebody.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes VC++ volatiles are supposed to guarantee fencing [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B.2B)

Comment: @Inge I thought we were talking about C++? The programming language? Are we in fact discussing some specific implementation and platform then?

Comment: It is not tagged as a dialect, so everyone assume ISO C++

Comment: Concerning the singleton, you can replace it by a non-singleton, references of which get passes around. That keeps the dependencies clear. Concerning concurrent access, if any of the threads are writing to the singleton, then one technique you can use is a wrapper that serialized concurrent accesses to a shared resource, and executes these in a separate worker thread. Herb Sutter gave a great talk about that, and I put together some compilable code. See [here](http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/concurrent-object-wrapper-c11/) for more on that(and sorry for the shameless plug).

Comment: BTW please use better link descriptions than "link".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `volatile` keyword in C++ is NOT the same as in any other languages. In C++ it means that the compiler will make sure that the value is always newly read from memory, and never a cached value is used.

It has it's uses the embedded world and other places. If you wanted to have an always up to date view of a certain variable you'd mark it as `volatile`.

It has nothing however to do with multithreading.

You should not use a singleton in a multi-threaded environment, because it will be a cause for contention as multiple threads try to access your object. It will cause your programs to lag and it entirely defeats using threads in the first place.

You should pass objects around, and you should be able to create new ones as you need them.

If you can't do that, review your design.

Comment: It has a lot to do with threading: if the value of a variable is cached in a register in one thread, then it can never be seen from another thread.

Comment: @infact While true, that is a laughably incomplete description of what does and does not constitute thread-safe data access. `volatile` simply isn't sufficient, so we shall not use it to "make my codez threadsafe"

Comment: I've read what you are saying in other articles, they always say "make an instance of your object and pass it around", sounds very simple but they never say just how. Some say "make a god object that creates all your instance objects", but you still end up with the problem of how all the treads are going to find this "god object" - you always end up with a static or singleton for that.

Comment: If the 'singleton' object has only invariant data and thread-safe member functions, why would it not be OK for multithreading?

Comment: 'a cause for contention as multiple threads try to access your object. It will cause your programs to lag' - only if you misuse it.